# Excel can't find path in macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having problem with macro which I've created to extract *.xml - excel table to chart on website.
It was working all the time but after a while I'm not able to run it.

Problem is with line below:

```
 Open path & "\xml_js\" & fileName For Output As 1
```

Macro is working perfectly fine when file is stored localy for example on my desktop but problem is when I'm trying to open it from mapped drive (sharepoint 2010).
It is working when I'm using my colleague computer (W7 + O2007) but not on mine (W7 + O2013).

I'm getting error below:

> Run-time error '52':
>      Bad file name or number

52 is exactly `Open path & (...) As 1` line

The rest of the code:

```
Sub generateRegionsFile()

  Dim fileName As String: fileName = "XXXXXX_Regions.xml"
  Dim path As String: path = ThisWorkbook.path

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
  Dim rowNum As Long: rowNum = 2
  Dim jsIndex As Long: jsIndex = 0

  Open path & "\xml_js\" & fileName For Output As 1

  Cells(15, 16).Select

  Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    NoOfStatuses = NoOfStatuses + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Loop
'Chart header
  Print #1, "<chart caption='No. of Items' subcaption='per Region' xaxisname='Region' yaxisname='Number of Region' showsum='0' numberprefix='' palette='3' rotatenames='0' animation='1'  basefont='Arial' basefontsize='12' useroundedges='' legendborderalpha='0' canvasbgalpha='0' bgcolor='#fffefe' bgalpha='50' plotgradientcolor='' showplotborder='0' showborder='0' showlegend='0'>"
  Print #1, ""
  Print #1, "   <categories>"

  Cells(15, 16).Select

    For x = 1 To NoOfStatuses
    Print #1, "       <category label='" & ActiveCell.Value & "' />"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Next

  Print #1, "   </categories>"
  Print #1, "   <dataset seriesname='Number of items'>"
  Cells(15, 17).Select
  For x = 1 To NoOfStatuses
  Print #1, "       <set value='" & ActiveCell.Value & "' />"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next

  Print #1, "   </dataset>"

  Print #1, "</chart>"

  Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: Please add further code in the question for designation of the variables path and filename in your prior code which could be leading to the error

Comment: You are confident you have the permissions associated with accessing that file...? Can you open it through other means?

Comment: @Cody G. I'm owner of the sharepoint so I have the highest permissions for that site, I've provided lower access permisions (Contribute level) and colleague is able to use macro without problem (on Excel 2007).

Comment: Is it really a 'mapped drive' ? It seems more like a URL to me. I would try using http GET to get the file. Alternatively if you want to try a different "open" I would suggest using FSO (file scripting object), but I suspect it won't change a whole lot. (Sorry I've never used sharepoint)

Answer (score 0):

Write this before the error:

```
debug.print  path & "\xml_js\" & fileName
```

You would see what you are trying to open. Probably your `path` is false or you are missing `\\` or something else.

Comment: Still I'm receiving that error, it's just going through debug.print. Macro is working fine on other computer with different software version

Comment: @JanKocon - of course! :) But see what is in the immediate window. Or write `msgbox path & "\xml_js\" & fileName` and see the result.

Comment: It's just showing me the exactly path https://troom-x.Companyname.com/sites/Sitename/dashboard/filename_status.xml which is true in that case

Comment: @JanKocon - now run it from your colleague's computer and see the difference between the paths.

Comment: I can see same path.

Comment: It could be an issue with forward slashes vs backslashes in the path name. You can't mix the two together.

Comment: @JanKocon - something in the path is not correct -  it if is this one (copied from your comment) - `troom-x.Companyname.com/sites/Sitename/dashboard/` then where is this part - `"\xml_js\"` ?

Comment: Actually I was aware of that and I've changed to "/xml_js/" before running macro